# Poetry: mysqlclient installing: failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, libmysqlclient

Getting this error running `poetry install`.

OS: Manjaro

python: 3.11.5

poetry: 1.6.1

I have no idea what's going

```
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing mysqlclient (2.1.1): Failed

  TypeError

  Can't instantiate abstract class IsolatedEnv with abstract methods make_extra_environ, python_executable

  at /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:109 in _prepare
      105│     ) -> Path:
      106│         from subprocess import CalledProcessError
      107│
      108│         with ephemeral_environment(self._env.python) as venv:
    → 109│             env = IsolatedEnv(venv, self._pool)
      110│             builder = ProjectBuilder(
      111│                 directory,
      112│                 python_executable=env.executable,
      113│                 scripts_dir=env.scripts_dir,
```

Comment: What poetry version, and how is poetry installed?

Comment: the poetry version is 1.6.1

Comment: For those who are interested: I fixed it by downgrading Poetry to 1.4.0, removing the lock file, and running `poetry install` again